# Poor and low quality on import/render Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere, video-editor, video-quality, codec, compression

I record a video step-by-step using Microsoft Expression Encoder 4, encode the file with 'Best Quality' preset, the result info in file its:

```
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : VC-1
Format profile                           : Advanced@L3
Codec ID                                 : WVC1
Codec ID/Hint                            : Microsoft
Description of the codec                 : VC-1 - VC-1 Advanced Profile
Duration                                 : 8mn 43s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 045 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 440 pixels
Height                                   : 900 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:10
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 15.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.054
Stream size                              : 65.2 MiB
```

When I play the video in VLC the quality its perfect.

[image: It´s a printscreen of video playing vlc]

After import the video in premiere and export sequence the video loss quality.

The printscreen above its the quality of exported video.

[image: the exported image]

```
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L5.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 5mn 53s
Bit rate                                 : 1 708 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 440 pixels
Height                                   : 900 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:10
Original display aspect ratio            : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 15.000 fps
Standard                                 : NTSC
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.088
Stream size                              : 72.0 MiB (90%)
```

When activating the option to export in Premiere , I have customized with the maximum possible quality.

Exporting in Adobe Premiere , using the same or better quality to the source video that was imported ?

Thank you all,

Comment: When you export in Premiere what codec are you using? h264?

Comment: i have the same problem but it shows up like that in premiere before i export it but the video itself is fine

Answer (score 1):

When exporting from Premiere there is a checkbox that says "match sequence settings" which will use the same format as your source video.

The "best quality" checkbox is Premiere does not refer to the codec, but to the internal scaling algorithms.